# How to inject one @Named bean in other @Named bean in JSF2?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I have the following code:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SearchBean{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    // .... getters and setter s
}
```

In `search.xhtml` I have:

```
<h:inputText value="#{searchBean.title}" />
<h:commandButton action=#{srchUI.action}"/>
```

And I have also the following ControllerBean:

```
@Named("srchUI")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchUIController {
    public String action(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to access the `SearchBean.title` in `action()` method... how to do it? How to inject this bean in my UI Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Inject`.

```
@Named("srchUI")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchUIController {

    @Inject
    private SearchBean searchBean;

    public String action(){

    }

}
```

Comment: could you explain this answer pls?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SearchUIController {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{searchBean}")
    private SearchBean searchBean;

    // .. setters and getters for the searchBean
}
```

Getters-setters are necessary.

Comment: That only works for `@ManagedBean` classes. OP is using CDI `@Named`.

Answer (score -2):

Use @Inject and add Get and Set methods on your injected bean!

```
@Named(value = "postMB")
@SessionScoped
public class PostMB{
   // inject comments on your posts
   @Inject
   private CommentMB commentMB;


   /* ADD GET and SET Methods to commentMB*/
   public CommentBM getCommentMB(){return this.commentMB;}
   public void setCommentMB(CommentMB newMB){this.commentMB = newMB;}
}


@Named(value="commentMB")
@RequestScoped
public class CommentMB{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Getters/setters are unnecessary for `@Inject`. Perhaps you're confusing with `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: in my case, work with get and set! but I don't tryed without get and Set.. I will do it now! ... NOTE: I'm using eclipse+Wildfly+JAP(Hibernate). so.. thank you for your feedback!