# How to send inputtext value to many backing beans in jsf

Tags: jsf

I'm using jsf 2 and i want to send h:inputText value for different managed beans.

JSF code:

```
<h:inputText value="#{outgoingMsgsAction.msisdn .... }" 
             required="true"
             requiredMessage="Please enter mobile number" 
             placeholder="International format"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind your input value to one object (in one bean). If you want to replicate your value in multiple beans, you need an value change listener and there set the value to multiple beans.

To access different beans you can for example [`@Inject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496193/how-to-inject-one-named-bean-in-other-named-bean-in-jsf2) them or use [OmniFaces Beans](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans) if you are using CDI.

For example:

```
public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    beanB.setValueX(event.getNewValue());
    beanC.setValueX(event.getNewValue());
}
```

XHTML:

```
<h:inputText value="#{beanA.valueX}"
             valueChangeListener="#{beanA.valueChangeListener}"
             .../>
```

Knowing that you are able to access other beans, it might be a good idea to simply store your value in one bean and access that value where you need it. Replicating the value seems like a hack to me, and might get you into trouble when a value is only changed in one of the beans.

See also:

- [how to use value change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166840/how-to-use-value-change-listener)